# Latex and Sweave, cannot include figure

Tags: r, include, latex, sweave

I have a file for my thesis, which include the chapters.
A few weeks ago, I worked with R-Statistic and `*.rnw` files to produce a `*.tex` paper.
Now, I want to include these `*.tex` paper in my thesis. However, every time I get several errors.

1. Structure

   ```
   /home/UserName/R-files/Dokumentation5.rnw 

   /home/UserName/tex-Files/Dokumentation5.tex  // from Dokumentation5.rnw files
   ```
2. In the following folder, I put the TeX and the figures (`*.pdf`).

   ```
   /home/UserName/Documentation/chapter/
   ```
3. Edit the `Dokumentation5.tex`, remove the beginning and "end document"
4. In thesis file, I added the following commands:

   ```
   \usepackage{Sweave}    \include /home/UserName/Documentation/chapter/
   ```
5. run `latex`

If I run LaTeX, I got several errors like:

```
File `Dokumentation5-004' not found.

 \begin{document} ended by \end{Schunk}.

 Too many }'s

 File `Dokumentation5-033' not found.
```

Comment: How about you make the whole thesis in sweave (knitr?)? I would make a master .Rnw file and use \include to add different chapters.

Comment: What is the easiest way?

Comment: If I may recommend [my older post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366193/writing-big-documents-with-sweave-is-it-possible-to-do-as-with-latex/8366504#8366504)...

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a file `master.Rnw` that contains nothing but the LaTeX setup (packages to be used, geometry, title, begin/end document, bibliography style and file......)
2. If you need to use R functions in various places in your paper, create a file `func.Rnw` where you create these functions. Make this file the first to `\SweaveInput{func.Rnw}` in your `master.Rnw` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366193/writing-big-documents-with-sweave-is-it-possible-to-do-as-with-latex?rq=1) for details
3. Now create one file for each "unit" of your paper (chapter, section, whatever you like). Make them all `chapX.Rnw` files, whether they contain R code or not.
4. `\SweaveInput{chapX.Rnw}` them in the desired order in your `master.Rnw` file.
5. At any time during the process, run `Sweave("master.Rnw")` in R and then `pdflatex master.tex` from the console to see what you have produced.

Comment: Hi, i created a master file and copied all style into this file. However there a some problems. First, Latex "says": to many "}". Second, if I include all *.rnw with \SweaveInput, Sweave("master.rnw") return the error: Error c("page.rnw", "master" is not ASCII and does not declare an encoding)

Comment: If LaTeX says "Too many `}`", then there are probably too many `}`. Do you have an editor that highlights open and close `}`? You may need to go through each of your files and make sure that you only have matching pairs. For the encoding problem, try adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Which language are you using?